# .on() not adding event to items added from an ajax based fnDraw() in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

When a checkbox is pressed a datatable retrieves new data via fnDraw() using ajax. The .on() event however is not adding the event correctly.

```
$("#reviewcheck").click(function() { reviewTable.fnDraw(); });

$(".review tbody td img").on("click", function () 
                {
                    console.log("here");
                    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                    var hide = document.getElementsByName(reviewTable.fnGetData(nTr)[23] + "h")[0];
                    if ( this.src.match(\'details_close\') )
                    {
                        var name = document.getElementsByName(reviewTable.fnGetData(nTr)[23] + "c")[0];
                        hide.value = name.value;
                                                this.src = "images/details_open.png";
                                                reviewTable.fnClose( nTr );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Open this row */
                        this.src = "images/details_close.png"
                        reviewTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(reviewTable, nTr), \'details\' );
                                                var name = document.getElementsByName(reviewTable.fnGetData(nTr)[23] + "c")[0];
                        name.value = hide.value;
                    }
                } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$(".review tbody td img").on("click", function ()
```

with

```
$('body').on("click",".review tbody td img", function ()
```

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is slightly different for [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(".review").on("click", ' tbody td img', function () {
})
```

(Assuming the `.review` element is not dynamically added)

The event must be bound to an element which is already present in the dom(left selector used before `on()`), and then the dynamic element selector must be passed as the second argument to [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)